# How does render template render the custom templates into the outlets defined in the default template used by a route.

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a scenario in which in a specific route i have two outlets and in the same route i want to show two different templates in two different outlets.

**Details template:**

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="details">
    Details Template
    {{#linkTo "index"}}Home{{/linkTo}}
    <hr/>
    <h4>DETAILS</h4>
    <hr/>
    <div class='outletArea'>
    {{outlet "detailsList"}}
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class='outletArea'>
    {{outlet "detailsMatrix"}}
    </div>
</script>
```

**Route is defined as:**

```
App.DetailsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
renderTemplate: function () {
    this._super();//to render the details temlate whch has outlets
    this.render('detailsList', { outlet: 'detailsList' });//render the list in list outlet
    this.render('detailsMatrix', { outlet: 'detailsMatrix' });//rendet the matrix in matrix outlet
    }
});
```

But those two template are not getting rendered in those two outlets rather they get rendered in the root element directely.

Fiddle for my proble is http://jsfiddle.net/anshulguleria/eCTtu/

As in jsfiddle i wanted these two temlates to get rendered in the grey areas. Thus when going through the link my rendered templates are not removed and rendered again and again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `details` route is at the top level, so when calling `render` in its `renderTemplate` function without specifying the `into` option, it tries to find these outlets in the top level template (i.e. in the `application` template). You can see it in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lcoq/ApmZ6/).

If you were in a nested route, it search them in the parent template (AFAIK).

Consequently, you just have to add the `into` option like this:

```
this.render('detailsList', { outlet: 'detailsList', into: 'details' });
this.render('detailsMatrix', { outlet: 'detailsMatrix', into: 'details' });
```

And [it works!](http://jsfiddle.net/lcoq/2NfXx/1/)

**EDIT**

It looks like Ember expect to have an `application` template that has an `{{outlet}}`.
It seems to be a bug in Ember, I think you can post an issue in github.

I've updated [the link above](http://jsfiddle.net/lcoq/2NfXx/1/) to add an application template.

Comment: actually it does not works. I accessed the link above and when I click on gotoIndex and gotoDetails, it should switch between the routes. Instead it appends the new view at the end which goes on continuously.

Comment: thanks, that worked this way, but I didn't wanted to use the application template because in my case I will be having many Ember applications and they can't have their separate application template.

Comment: Why ? I guess you can define an application view like this: `App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({templateName: "app1"})`, and do the same in another application

Comment: Instead of `this._super();//to render the hotel temlate whch has outlets` you could now do this: `this.render();` This wil render the default outlet.